# What is the best practice for ddos protection on Windows Azure virtual machine?

Tags: security, azure

What is the best practice for ddos protection on Windows Azure virtual machine?
I have multiple domains connected to my vm
and a static ip

Answer (score 2):

Azure provides DDOS protection on all their services, but they do this in a selfish manner.  IE:  They are protecting their service, not necessarily yours.

I think when trying to enable DDOS protection you have the following options

- Use VMs from the Azure Marketplace.  There are leading security
  solutions for sale, and you can put those in-line with your VMs
- Use an upstream service such as [Incapsula](https://www.incapsula.com/), [cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/), or
  [Silverline](https://f5.com/products/platforms/silverline/f5-silverline-cloud-based-ddos-protection)

There really is no one single best practice solution, you need to balance cost vs risk to determine the best solution for you or your client.

Answer (score 0):

Azure officially partners with Imperva Incapsula to provide WAF and DDoS Mitigation:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-security-center-adds-new-partners-detections-and-more/
https://www.incapsula.com/ddos-protection-for-microsoft-azure.html

If you want a hint, look at who protects Microsoft's own blog...
http://blogs.microsoft.com/blog/2016/02/25/enterprise-security-for-our-mobile-first-cloud-first-world-2/

Answer (score 0):

Using `incapsula` is the correct way to go, it will mitigate all of the ddos attack, provide CDN and Cache for your app which will speed it up.

Today we use `incapsula` to mitigate both attacks and as a CDN + cache and it actually saved us on AWS traffic and speed up the application.

Answer (score -1):

There is a lot happening around making Azure more secure. Most of that is described in [the Azure Trust Center](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/trust-center/). You can [request the penetration testing](https://security-forms.azure.com/penetration-testing/terms) as well if you want.

And, if you want some additional features, there is partners offerings marketplace called Azure Marketplace where you can find a lot of [manageable solutions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/?term=ddos).